# wordpress set post_status as "draft" in 'save_post' action

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom function that works with my custom post type. While porocessing `save_post` action:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_custom_function' );
```

I would like to set post status as draft (in case of a problem with getting custom data from outside api).
In my `my_custom_function` function I have this little block:

```
if ($error == true) {
    $override_post = array();
    $override_post['ID'] = $post_id;
    $override_post['post_status'] = 'draft';
    wp_update_post( $override_post );
}
```

but it seems, that after `save_post` is being processed, then `post_status` is being set again.

Anybody have an idea, where should I hook into, so while saving post data I can modify its `post_status`, `post_date` and some other post data informations so they are not being overriten?

Answer (score 4):

You should hook it to [`wp_insert_post_data`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data). Then you could use a function like this to set your post status to draft:

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'set_post_to_draft', 99, 2 );

function set_post_to_draft( $data, $postarr ) {

  if ( your_condition ) {
    $data['post_status'] = 'draft';
  }

  return $data;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the same with a custom parameter in function callout?

Comment: Never mind, just have uset post_meta to send a correct variable.

Comment: Hmm. It seems that this method creates a problem. If user only opens new-post.php but doesnt save it - the automatic saved draft is created that can't be managed by wordpress (the function pushes `post_status` not only on save but also on opening of `post-new.php`).

Comment: Are you hooking using `wp_insert_post_data`? Is it when you load the page or the autosave that is triggering your function?

Comment: Exactly this hook is cousing a problem. And only loading a post-new.php is enought to create an enty in database. I have wrote about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792948/wordpress-hooking-into-saving-post-data. It seems more complicated problem, and I think the only "safe" way is to use wpdb to alter data.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make a post type with only one post_status option, and it seem to fit your needs too, as it is works exactly with the `save_post` hook.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_function' );
function my_function( $post_id ){
    if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ){
        // avoid endless circle
        remove_action('save_post', 'my_function');

        // update the data before saving
        wp_update_post( wp_slash([
            'ID' => $_POST['ID'],
            'post_status' => 'draft'
        ]));

        // restore the saving hook
        add_action('save_post', 'my_function');
    }
}
```

The original solution found here:
https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_update_post